# Cutting numbers into a specific decimals

Tags: command-line

I want to cut all numbers in a file to the fifth decimal only. For example, I have this file:

```
Ga O # 83645, Ga2O3                     
1.0
       12.2348604202         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         3.0320000648         0.0000000000
       -1.3752052829         0.0000000000         5.6183021388
   Ga    O
    8   12
Direct
     0.590021042         0.500000000         0.794251030
     0.409978979         0.500000000         0.205748985
     0.909978943         0.000000000         0.205749006
     0.090021023        -0.000000000         0.794251030
     0.658887031         0.000000000         0.314083014
```

So, I want to have the same file but with numbers with 5 decimal places only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind the integers also being converted to floating point, you could use `numfmt`:

```
$ numfmt --field=1- --format=%.5f --invalid=ignore < file
1.00000
            12.23487              0.00000              0.00000
             0.00000              3.03201              0.00000
            -1.37521              0.00000              5.61831
   Ga    O
8.00000 12.00000
Direct
         0.59003             0.50000             0.79426
         0.40998             0.50000             0.20575
         0.90998             0.00000             0.20575
         0.09003             0.00000             0.79426
         0.65889             0.00000             0.31409
```

#### Explanation

- `--field=1-`

  This option tells `numfmt` which occurrences need to be replaced. `1-` in this case means from the first occurrence until the end of the line.
- `--format=%.5f`

  This option tells `numfmt` how to format the output numbers. `%.5f` in this case means format them as floating numbers with 5 decimal digits.
- `--invalid=ignore`

  This option tells `numfmt` what to do in case it was not able to format a number. `ignore` in this case just ignores the problematic input and carries on with next input.

By default, `numfmt` applies [IEEE 754 rounding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) - if you want simple truncation, you can add `--round=towards-zero`. The complete list of rounding options is `up`, `down`, `from-zero` (default), `towards-zero`, `nearest`.

You can view manpage for more details:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/numfmt.1.html

---

If you want IEEE 754 rounding but want it to apply strictly to floating point numbers with more than 5 digits after the point, then I'd suggest using `perl` - it can match regular expressions, like `sed`, but allows you to apply a `sprintf` expression to the captured pattern:

```
perl -pe 's/[+-]?\d*[.]\d{5,}/sprintf "%.5f", $&/ge' file
```

Like GNU `sed`, `perl` can modify the file in-place by adding the `-i` option.

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know about `numfmt`. If you don't care about converting integers to decimals, this has the benefit of also rounding the numbers, which the rest of the solutions don't address. Perhaps you can combine your solution with regex to apply it to decimals only.

Comment: `numfmt` seems to be always rounding up positive numbers and rounding down negative numbers. For example, `12.2348604202` -> `12.23487` and `-1.3752052829` -> `-1.37521`. I would assume this would be fine in most cases, but in some cases, this may not be a desirable output.

Comment: @Dan `numfmt` has a `--round` option that you can play with: `--round=towards-zero` appears to be equivalent to truncation (but I haven't tested it exhaustively)

Comment: @steeldriver You are right, however in that case you would have to manually account for the rounding, whereas `numfmt` can do it by itself.

Comment: @steeldriver Just a note (add it if you want to your answer): I use `el_GR.UTF8` as my numeric format, which uses comma (`,`) as a decimal separator, so the decimal numbers weren't recognized as such. Only the integers were converted. To remedy this, I added `LC_NUMERIC=C` before the command and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Dan `--round=nearest` applies the conventional rounding.

Comment: @user3140225 I've added a `perl`-based regex version that applies the same `%.5f` formatting only to the target floating point numbers - unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do that with `numfmt` itself

Comment: @steeldriver Excellent!

Comment: I can't seem to get format to work: `14894080 | numfmt --from-unit=1000 --from=iec --to=iec --format=%.5f` (I'm getting the number from `ps -q $PID -eo rss --no-headers`). The error is invalid format, `'%.5f', directive must be %['][-][N]f`.  The version is `numfmt (GNU coreutils) 8.22`

Comment: @CeePlusPlus I think your version is simply too old - `numfmt` was only included in coreutils 8.21 and the ability to handle decimal precision appears to have been added in coreutils 8.24 (released 2015). Are you using a currently supported version of Ubuntu?

Comment: In full transparency I'm not ubuntu, this is where I landed when trying to find something on Google :), so I guess that explains it for now

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{5})[0-9]*/\1/g' file
```

Add `-i` option to add file in place.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/\.([0-9]{5})[0-9]*/.\1/g' file
```

Output:

```
1.0
       12.23486         0.00000         0.00000
        0.00000         3.03200         0.00000
       -1.37520         0.00000         5.61830
   Ga    O
    8   12
Direct
     0.59002         0.50000         0.79425
     0.40997         0.50000         0.20574
     0.90997         0.00000         0.20574
     0.09002        -0.00000         0.79425
     0.65888         0.00000         0.31408
```

---

Use extended regular expressions with `-E`:

`sed -E`

---

Match the pattern `.<five digits><n digits>` with `\.([0-9]{5})[0-9]*`. Capture the 5 digits following the dot `.` with `([0-9]{5})`

```
s/\.([0-9]{5})[0-9]*/
```

---

Replace the match with the dot `.` and the captured pattern:

`/.\1/`

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk '{print gensub(/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{5})[0-9]*/, "\\1", "g")}' input_file > output_file
```

This uses the `awk` function `gensub` to select a decimal number (`/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{5})[0-9]*/`) from a given file (`input_file`) and split it into two parts. The first part has 5 decimal places (`([0-9]+\.[0-9]{5})`) and the second part is the rest of the decimal number (`[0-9]*`).

`gensub` then replaces the selected number with its first part (`"\\1"`) and does that for all the decimal numbers it can find (`"g"`) in `input_file`.

The command then saves the result to an output file (`> output_file`).